# matplotlib: Continuously overwriting

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to plot my intermediate results and want to see how is the algorithm progressing. I have posted a demo code too. Lets say my algorithm goes for 20 epochs and I want to plot the result of every epoch in a same file. I tried with following demo code. But I can not see any plot on a.png.

Could someone help me how could I do it?

```
import  matplotlib.pylab  as plt 
import numpy as np


for i in range(20):
  y = np.random.random()
  plt.plot(i, y)
  plt.savefig('a.png')
```

Comment: Grab a refernce to the `Line2D` object and use `set_data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide the whole history in your variables e.g. as a list:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt 
import numpy as np

# creates two lists with the same length
x = range(20)
y = [0] * 20
for i in x:
  y.insert(i, np.random.random())
  plt.plot(x, y)
  plt.savefig('plot_%d.png' % i)
```